# SpriteKit - update energy over time across multiple scenes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I’ve got a game where I want to update an “energy” bar over time. So every 5 minutes the player should gain one more energy point to use. I’d know how to do this on a single scene, but this is something that should update regardless of what scene you are on and also in the background but I’m struggling with how best to achieve this.

For the background I think I’ve got this covered. When the application is sent to the background I store the time and when it enters the foreground again I get the current time and work out how much energy they should get.

What I’m struggling with is the best way to manage this across scenes and update the UI accordingly (I plan to display this in the top left of all screens). My first thought is to have a singleton object that reads the stored energy level and has a timer (outside of sprite kits update loop). This runs every 5 minutes and updates the energy level. It could then post a notification so that any non SpriteKit views can display the current energy, similarly any SpriteKit scenes can just use the update loop to read the value and display it accordingly.  But I’m unsure if this is a valid approach.

Should I just have an object attached to the appdelegate to do something similar to the Singleton. This would allow me to easily compare times when the application became active again (e.g if it was 2.5 mins in to refreshing the energy level)

Can anyone suggest if this is a good approach or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two questions here if I understood this correctly; one regarding showing the energy bar regardless of scene and one for calculating the energy gained during the time the app has been closed.

As for the first question (displaying the energy bar in all scenes) you should take a look at [SKReferenceNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skreferencenode)

What I did in one of my games with a global menu was this:
I created a separate SpriteKit scene (.sks file) for the menu. I then added the SKReferenceNode in the GameScene.sks file. In GameScene.swift file I just treated the ReferenceNode as a normal SKSpriteNode like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

// Reference node added in GameScene.sks
var playerHealthBar : SKSpriteNode!


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // Reference node
    playerHealthBar = self.childNode(withName: “//playerHealthBar”) as? SKSpriteNode

 }
```

}

With a SKReferenceNode you can implement that node in all of our scenes. You'll then be able to update the node at any time. I use that method for creating global menubars in my games (where ex. a users gold, health points etc. can be displayed)

And for the data regarding the playerHealthBar (ex. healthpoints) you can load/save this from UserDefaults.

As for the second question an idea would be to store a variable called `lastActive` in UserDefaults. Update this value when the app is entering the background.

When the app enters foreground you need to compare the current time to the `lastActive` variable.

Take a look at this:

```
 func timeSpentAwayInSeconds() -> Int {
    // We then check when the player was last active
    let lastActive = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastActive")

    // Then we compare that to the current date
    let elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(lastActive as! Date)

    // Covert that to seconds
    let elapsedTimeInSeconds : Int = Int(elapsedTime)

    return elapsedTimeInSeconds
}
```

I hope this help a bit. Please mark as answered if it solved your problem :-)

Happy coding!

Comment: I think it’s slightly more conceptual then that around where you would actually create an object like this. i.e should it be a singleton that resides in the appdelegate is all I can think of at hand, I don’t know if there’s a better design pattern to achieve this in the concept of SpriteKit

Comment: Can you show an example of how you update your global menu bars etc? As using the referenceNode my energy value is getting reset when moving to a new scene (I'm assuming because it seems to be reloading the reference again). It feels more like I need to go a different route with how I approach this

Comment: I have updated my post with a more detailed explanation and sample code.

Comment: I think there's some crossed wires here,I get how I can use the reference node across multiple scenes for display purposes,but it's about the best way to manage the data in relation to that. Ultimately I can persist it in an object that conforms to NSCoding. But then should each scene just create a new instance of this "playerData" on load, or should I just have a single one(perhaps attached to the appDelegate) bearing in mind the value will update every 5 mins, should I then use something like KVO or just rely on the update method to read the latest values?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I'd declare a `dictionary` outside our class and when the app opens you can load all of your game data into that dictionary. In that way you'll be able to access all of your game data from all of your scenes. Then when the app closes, goes into background or so on, you can save the data of the dictionary into ex. userDefaults. I hope that makes sence. Let me know if you need some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those rare circumstances where you want to use `Timer`.

```
let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(5)
let timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(runCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
```

This is because you are dependent on real world time, not in game time.

Now keep in mind you need to keep track of any misfires from the timer because you are off doing other things.  Your `runCode` function should link to delegates of the scenes you are updating and also should not be incrementing.  Instead it should be checking the last time your code fired and compare it to the current time your code fired to determine how many points to add.  It should behave exactly the same way as the code you use when leaving and returning to the app.

Now if you need to perform any UI updates,  I would suggest attaching it to an SKAction that you attach to the scene,  this way if your scene is in a paused stated or not loaded, it will fire when the scene resumes.  This also guarantees that your UI changes are being done on the main thread, as opposed to whatever thread your timer may be on.

Now depending on how you are designing your game, I would recommend another approach.  If you have multiple scenes all with the same overlay,  then I would recommend the overlay not even be a part of SpriteKit.  Instead, create a UIView layer that lays on top of your SpriteKit scenes.  What this view does is take nodes that do not need to be updated every frame outside of your scene,  allowing your scene to perform faster since it has to render, sort, and filter between less nodes.  On top of that, you only need to update 1 view, as opposed to X amount of scenes.